# How to get next date in repeated ID sequences in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table that has multiple occurrences of its id and the date. For example:

```
     id #       date
1    abc        2014-Apr-05
2    def        2015-Mar-07
3    def        2014-Feb-02
4    abc        2013-Oct-23
5    abc        2016-Jan-10
6    xyz        2016-Jul-18
7    def        2014-Sep-03
8    xyz        2015-May-25
9    def        2013-Nov-11
10   abc        2015-Aug-16
```

I am wondering how I can scroll through the id's and then through the dates and return the lowest/earliest date for each id. Such as:

```
     id #    date
1    abc     2013-Oct-23
2    def     2013-Nov-11
3    xyz     2015-May-25
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "first next" date?

Comment: Your table with expected result doesn't make sense. In the last row of the expected result you want to see `xyz` with the date `2015-May-07`. Where does this date `2015-May-07` come from? It is not in the original data.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Извинияюсь - очепятка. Должно было быть 2015-May-25

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen by first next date I mean the soonest date. So if there are for example years 2013, 2014 and 2015 then to return 2013. It is the earliest date.

Comment: So you mean the lowest date. It is important that you describe in full what you want because otherwise you're going to get answer that doesn't answer your question. By the time you've corrected this, the question may have fallen off the front page, and also gotten a few (incorrect) answers, which makes it less probable that new people will look at it. Your chance of getting a right answer decreases significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Window Function` to find the `first date` in each `[id#]` group

```
SELECT [id#],
       [date]
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY [id#]
                   ORDER BY [date] ASC) rn,
               *
        FROM   tablename)a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c06e/2)

Or Use `Aggregate` and `Join`. Find the `minimum date` in each `Id#` and `join` the result with main table.

```
SELECT a.[id#],
       a.[date]
FROM   Tablename A
       JOIN (SELECT Min([date]) dates,
                    [id#]
             FROM   Tablename
             GROUP  BY [id#]) B
         ON a.[date] = b.[date]
            AND a.[id#] = b.[id#]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the expected result it can be done with a simple `GROUP BY` and `MIN` date.

```
SELECT
    [id #]
    , MIN([date]) AS FirstDate
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [id #]
ORDER BY [id #];
```

Comment: After clarification in comments, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE
  (
     id1   VARCHAR(10),
     date1 DATE
  )

INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES      ('abc',
             '2014-Apr-05'),
            ('def',
             '2015-Mar-07'),
            ('def',
             '2014-Feb-02'),
            ('abc',
             '2013-Oct-23'),
            ('abc',
             '2016-Jan-10'),
            ('xyz',
             '2016-Jul-18'),
            ('def',
             '2014-Sep-03'),
            ('xyz',
             '2015-May-25'),
            ('def',
             '2013-Nov-11'),
            ('abc',
             '2015-Aug-16')

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT id1,
               date1,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY id1
                   ORDER BY date1) c
        FROM   @t1) t
WHERE  t.c = 1
```